# Issues with sessions on Facebook PHP SDK

Tags: php, ajax, facebook, session, facebook-php-sdk

I want to make in my site buttons that `onclick` will post on user facebook wall a message.
I call an AJAX script from php pages in my site that send the message in _POST to the php file with the facebook code.

I'm getting this ERROR while running my php file:

> Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send
>   session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at
>   /home/user/public_html/fb/index.php:1) in
>   /home/user/public_html/fb/facebook.php on line 49

my PHP look like this:

```
<?php
include('../ilink.php'); //mysqli connection

$fb_message=$_POST['fb_message'];
$fb_description=$_POST['fb_description'];
$fb_picture=$_POST['fb_picture'];


require 'facebook.php';

// Create our Application instance.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => '--appid--',
    'secret' => '--secret--',
    'cookie' => true
));

    $user  = $facebook->getUser(); 

    if ($user) {
      try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.
        $user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
      } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
        $user = null;
      }
    }

    // Login or logout url will be needed depending on current user state.
    if ($user) {
      $logoutUrl = $facebook->getLogoutUrl();
    } else {
      $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl();
    }

    $attachment = array('message' => $fb_message,
            'name' => 'text',
            'caption' => 'text',
            'link' => 'http://www.domain.com',
            'description' => $fb_description,
            'picture' => $fb_picture,
            'actions' => array(array('name'=>'text', 
                              'link' => 'http://www.domain.com'),)
            );

    $result = $facebook->api('/me/feed/','post',$attachment);
?>
```

my ajax script:

```
    function fb_post(fb_message,fb_description,fb_picture,redirect){
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest){// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else{// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){

                document.location.href =redirect;               
          }
        }

        var q="fb_message="+fb_message+"&fb_description="+fb_description+"&fb_picture="+fb_picture;
        xmlhttp.open("POST","/fb/index.php",true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xmlhttp.send(q);
}
```

Why the ERROR appear?

Comment: As this error comes when body part send require head part sent again. Please remove any space from the top of the page from all the files

Answer (score 0):

If this is your all code, it looks like something in included file sent headers before session instance.

Comment: I have Session in each page on my site (for user login). and there is session on the facebook.php. Maybe i need to destroy the session in some way? And Rohit Kumar - I dont have white spaces.

Comment: What do you mean on each page you got session, you dont have to start session on every page, show more code.

Comment: I have in each page this include (username.php) for konwing who the user that login in right now, this page start with those lines: <?php
session_start();
$user_id=$_SESSION['logon'];
include("ilink.php");